# Excel - Validate data based on dependent fields

Tags: excel, validation, dependencies

Hoping someone can help on this. I am trying to identify where values are invalid.

I have a set of data that contains correct values for three fields where they are dependent of each other.Table 1 (Correct Dataset)

I have another set of data that contains values within these three fields and contains invalid values. How can I easily identify where the values are invalid? Table 2 (Invalid Dataset)

Table 1 (Correct Dataset):

```
Letter    Color     ProductName
A         Red       Product A
B         Blue      Product B
B         Orange    Product C
C         Red       Product D
```

Table 2 (Invalid Dataset)

```
Letter    Color     ProductName
A         Red       **Product D**
B         **Red**   Product B
B         Orange    Product C
**D**     **Blue**  Product D
```

Comment: Conditional formatting comparing the value of each pair of cells?

Comment: There is some ambiguity about how you apply the validation rules:
In the case of (A, Red, Product D), you marked **Product D** as being invalid, but in the case of (D, Blue, Product D), you marked **D** and **Blue** as being invalid. Why wouldn't the last one be handled as **D**, Blue,**Product D**? 

Normally we need a reference column (a primary key), and compare everything against that, or we only compare and mark entire rows as being invalid (not individual columns). Is there a key here?